# Manually assigning page META tags to asp.net dynamic pages

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I just first want to say, thanks for taking the time to read this!

I have an e-commerce website running the content management system DotNetNuke, which I believe is built on the asp.net platform in a windows server environment. The specific module that powers my e-commerce store dynamically generates pages for each of the store categories, as a user browses through the products available. As you may be aware, modules such as these must be placed on a specific page, and all the dynamic content generated by the module must reside on that "parent page".

The problem is that while the module does allow me to add HTML text for H1's and H2's on these dynamic pages, it does not support adding page meta tags such as "title" and "description". As a result, all of the dynamic pages generated by the module pull their meta tags from the parent page, making it difficult for Google to understand what I'm trying to show the user. This also causes google to show all these generated pages as having "duplicate title tags" in my analytics.

The temporary fix:
I have removed the title tags from all of these "parent pages", in hopes that google will decide to generate it's snippits from the H1 and H2 tags residing on the dynamic pages. Was this wise?

**Now for the question:
Is there any kind of solution available which would allow me to manually assign meta tags to a page I specify in my hosting environment? As I stated earlier, I am able to add body HTML code to pages. Is there any way to force a page title tag from code placed in the body? Is there a better way to do this? You can view my problem in action at www.yandasmusic.com**

Thanks for your time and patience!
Alex

Comment: How did you remove the title tags from the "parent pages"?  The title tag is dynamically generated in DotNetNuke, and you couldn't remove it from one page without removing it from all of them...

Comment: Sorry if my wording was incorrect. The module that generates the categories resides on a single page that I created in DNN. In the DNN settings I removed the title and description tags for that page. So now, all the dynamically generated content from the module still resides on that page, but that page has no title tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The temporary fix: I have removed the title tags from all of these "parent pages", in hopes that google will decide to generate it's snippits from the H1 and H2 tags residing on the dynamic pages. Was this wise?
>   Blockquote

No, not particularly wise.  The page title is important.

The first route you should take is speaking to the module developer.  They should know about replacing page meta information on a per-product basis.

You can get (limited) results by varying the page title/description using javascript when the page loads.  Just keep the js simple and use the DOM information already on the page (ie, read the product name).

I posted a blog about this recently : http://www.ifinity.com.au/2012/10/04/Changing_a_Page_Title_with_Javascript_to_update_a_Google_SERP_Entry

The javascript fix will probably work if you set it up correct.  But you really need to convince the module developer to change the way the module works, as bdukes has posted.

Don't bother with the Meta Tags - none of the search engines really read/use them because they are so easily spoofed.  Just concentrate on the title and description of the page.

Comment: Excellent Bruce - This is exactly what I needed! I have contacted Smith Consulting, and they have added it to their "feature requests list". If you wouldn't mind - I have very little experience with Javascript. I want to use the line of JS on your blog post, but I will need it to pull from the H1 tag on the current page. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Or is there a way to manually set the title using your JS snippit within the code itself. As it stands with the module, I will have to go in and add the code to each category individually anyways.

Comment: As I understand the script, I can specify the ID on the page to pull from an element on the page with that ID. So for example of the ID of TEST <script type="text/javascript">setTimeout(function() { document.title = "iFinity User Profile - " + document.getElementById("TEST").outerText;}, 1000); </script>     and then give my H1 tag the id of TEST. What about the portion that contains the test "ifinity user profile - "?

Comment: More research completed. Sorry, maybe I should research before I post... Every page that needs this code, has an H1 element with the class of "Category-H1". I found this code snippit, but it's not working. <script type="text/javascript">
    document.title = document.getElementsByClassName('Category-H1');
</script> My page titles are coming up as [object HTMLCollection]

Comment: Got it figured out here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094340/dynamically-change-page-title-from-h1-tag-using-javascript

Comment: OK you got it now.  Check the SERPs over the next few weeks and see if your pages have had the titles changed by google executing the javascript in the crawling of the pages.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, your store module should be setting the page title and other meta information.  In DotNetNuke, you can access the `Title`, `MetaDescription`, and `MetaKeywords` of the page by casting `Page` the `DotNetNuke.Framework.CDefault` type.  If the store module doesn't provide this, you should ask the developer to add the functionality.

Comment: I did contact the developers, and they have added it to their "requested enhancements" list. I was hoping I could find a temporary solution in the mean time.